# Get posts in between specific ID's

Tags: get-posts

I want to get the posts from within specific ID's ( *10 - 15* ), just like we do in SQL

```
select * from employees limit 10 , 20 ;
```

I wanna get in this Wordpress posts.

Comment: This SQL query is about paging, but not finding specific range of ID's. The solution by @PieterGoosen should give you that range in an easy way.

Answer (score 2):

You can simply just use the `post__in` parameter inside your query arguments or inside your `pre_get_posts` action

### EXAMPLE

(*Adjust as necessary. Code requires at least PHP 5.4+ due to short array syntax (`[]`)*)

```
$args = [
    'post__in' => range( 10, 15 ),
];
$q = get_posts( $args );
var_dump( $q );
```